# Deterministic build is not really deterministic in .NET 6

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-6.0

I set `<Deterministic>` to true in my `.csproj` file as specified in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/code-generation#deterministic) to create deterministic outputs.

I need any team member on any machine to be able to create the exactly same DLL when builds our project.

However, when I build, and compare my DLL files to my teammate's DLL files, I see that some files are different.

How can I debug this? How can I find out where the problem might be?

We have the same versions of .NET SDK and Visual Studio. We have the same versions of Windows. Almost everything is the same.

I want to know how can I troubleshoot this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that all elements mentioned under the given documentation are really exactly equal? The list is so long that I think it's next to impossible to have two computers be equal in all points.

Comment: The problem is exactly that list. It's so vague. And deterministic build should not be dependent upon anything, but the source code and the compiler version. In other words, give the same source code to the same version of the compiler and receive the same output. But this is not what we get.

Comment: Also how can I compare them together. Is it possible to somehow log the build process such that we can compare logs together to find out the differences?

Comment: I agree, that's way to complicated. However, can you explain why you think you need that feature? I have never come across the need for this and I'm unsure why they added it.

Comment: We need deterministic build. Our product needs to be approved by governments all over the world. Each county has different regulation. We need to demonstrate that our source code is surely the souse of the binary. Getting the same binary at a government's lab explains the source and binary are identical. Since it is requested from  many governments, we cannot avoid it.

Comment: It's possible problem is somewhere in here: https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/issues/601